# How do I exclude my API KEY pushing to github?

Tags: heroku, github

if I exclude the file with API KEY and push to gitHub and then to Heroku the app doesn't work because the app can't get access to the api key.

What is the workaround? I'm quite a novice so comments or info with human readable language would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think the 'proper' way to do this is using Heroku's config vars settings: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars (specifically the 'Settings' tab in the dashboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the API key as an environment variable.

In heroku, go to your app, then settings and click on "Reveal Config Vars".
In there you can store your API key for your deployed server to use. This is also where you will store DB urls too, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has interface for setting up environment variables.

[image]

So use environment variable locally (from environment or e.g. `.env` file) and remotely.

Also read on [12-factor-app](https://12factor.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of stuff should be kept in Heroku config variables. I find heroku command line more convenience. You can download it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install). Then, you can use this command to setup the new Heroku configVar at will.

```
heroku config:set API_KEY=1234567890 --app your_app_name
```

To see all configs,

```
heroku config --app your_app_name
```

Then, based on the language developed, you can access this configVar from code. For example, you can do this in Ruby on Rails' code.

```
 <%= ENV["MY_API"] %>
```